# HTML_IMAGE_ONLY_20 message when testing email

Tags: phpmailer, spam

I am sending an email to new users asking them to verify.

This is my email

[image]

But when I am testing the email in mail-tester.com, I get this HTML_IMAGE_ONLY_20 message. But I do not have any image sith text in or am I misunderstading the error?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that’s a SpamAssassin rule. It is a rule that says that your message is composed primarily of image and not text. In your example  you have a logo and not much text, so I’d assume it’s that. You could look up the source code for the SA rule and see what it’s actually looking for.